# How to match string , special characters and HTML tags in Regex?

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to match a HTML text mixed with some normal strings .
I've already do most of the job , but the problem with the string inside the HTML chars .

So the text i'm trying to find would look like this :

```
>(\n(optional))</td>\n<td style="text-align:right">Text i want</td>\n
```

So the main problem is the optional part because it has \n () and string , and all of it are optional .

what i've done so far is :

```
reg_num = r'></td>\\n<td style="text-align:right">.*?</td>\\n'
reg_num1 = r'(?<="\>).*?(?=\</)'
pattern = re.compile(reg_name)
pattern1 = re.compile(reg_num)
pattern2 = re.compile(reg_num1)
pup = re.findall(pattern1, str(html_text))
new_pup = re.findall(pattern2,str(pup))
```

What i did above is first found the text and then found the text i want .
this code works fine for all the result which doesn't have the optional text within.

What should i add in order to get the matches when there is optional text too ?

Is there any better way to find the text with one line without dividing it ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: downvote didn't come from me but this was the write way to do this job before Beautifulsoup was written. Not anymore

Comment: Noooooooo..., don't parse HTML with regexes. Use XPath, CSS selectors, jQuery selectors, or another tool...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem i dont understand

Comment: @james: HTML is *context-free language*. You cannot parse context-free languages with regular expressions. Regular expressions are meant to parse *regular languages*. The above stated tools are - so to speak - the "regexes for context-free languages".

Comment: Firstly you shouldn't use regex, Secondly you haven't provided enough strings to test the regex. Provide few lines that should match and others that shouldn't if you don't want to use a parser for some reason.

Comment: @MYGz It's not that i don't what to use it , i never used it ..

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem thanks i think i will use a parser .

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem can you please show how can i do it with a parser ?

Comment: @james: well you example is not very clear: you simply want to fetch the text of a `<td>` with `style="text-align:right"`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem ** right"> text i want</td>\n**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use a regex to parse HTML, you should use a tool like XPath queries or css/jQuery selectors.

A package that allows you to parse HTML is [`BeautifulSoup`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). For example:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(str(html_text))
for td_tag in soup.find_all('td',{'style':'text-align:right'}):
    print(td_tag.text) #or do something else with the text
```

Here you parse it to a `soup` object, and the you iterate over all `<td>` tags that have an attribute `style` that is exactly `"text-align:right"`. Now for all these `td_tag`s, you print the `.text` (evidently you can do something else with it).

If you for instance want to construct a list of all these texts, you can use *list comprehension*:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(str(html_text))
all_texts = [td_tag.text for td_tag in soup.find_all('td',{'style':'text-align:right'})]
```

As you can see, here you **specify** what you want to extract, there is no need to write complex regexes that can easily fail or even are impossible to construct. One can easily read what you aim to extract.

Answer (score -3):

I would recommend you to use `beautifulsoup` package of Python.

Comment: That's not really an answer: you should at least write the query stated in the question with beautifulsoup.

Comment: of course it is possible. I just gave you the easiest way.

Comment: @JayParikh: not per se there are queries you can write in XPath you **cannot** write with a regex.